# Why doesn't picocli recognize my option from the command line?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, picocli

I'm trying to build a CLI in Java using PICOCLI and I'm STUCK at a very basic point. I simply cannot get my application to consumer an option and it's value. Here's my class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import picocli.CommandLine;

@SpringBootApplication

@CommandLine.Command(name = "Greet", header = "%n@|green Hello world demo|@")
class DemoApplication implements Runnable {

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"-u", "--user"}, required = true, description = "The user name.")
    String userName;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + userName);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CommandLine.run(new DemoApplication(), System.err, args);
    }
}
```

I then do a `mvn package`, `cd target` and `java -jar demo-1.0.jar Greet -u pico` but I'm only met with this:

```
Unmatched argument at index 0: 'Greet'

Hello world demo
Usage: Greet -u=<userName>
  -u, --user=<userName>   The user name.
```

I have run out of patience trying to print a simple message ! I do not know how else to solve this. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you invoke the command with `java`, you don't need to specify the command name `Greet`, just specify the command line options:

```
java -jar demo-1.0.jar -u pico
```

You can think of it this way: `java -jar demo-1.0.jar` *is* the `Greet` command.

You may want to use the [Application Assembler Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/) to create a launcher script, and name that launcher script `Greet`.

That way, users of your program can invoke it on the command line with this command:

```
Greet -u pico
```

The maven config for AppAssembler should look something like this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <configuration>
          <programs>
            <program>
              <mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
              <id>Greet</id>
            </program>
          </programs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

UPDATE: I added a section to the user manual on [how to run picocli-based applications](https://picocli.info/#_running_the_application).

---

UPDATE 2: I recommend upgrading to the latest version of picocli; version 4.0 introduced a new [execute API](https://picocli.info/#execute) with better support for exit codes and error handling.

In your example, that would look like this:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
  int exitCode = new CommandLine(new DemoApplication()).execute(args);
  System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I had no idea why "Greet" wouldn't work! This is immensely helpful! Thank you :) 

Comment: Thank you for bringing it up! It inspired me to improve the manual and add that new section on how to run picocli-based apps, as well as brush up to the Packaging part of the manual. :thumbs-up: